# Fetching currently executing tasks for a flow

Tags: camunda

We just started with *camunda* and looking for api which can give us all tasks which are currently getting executed. I know that it does provide state information like **PENDING** and **COMPLETED** but I am particularly interested in "**EXECUTING**" state. Is there a way to find it? Is it safe to assume that if task is not in **COMPLETED/ERROR** and **PENDING** state, then it is getting executed?

**note**: using camunda 7.9.0 - Jboss packaging

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are talking about user tasks, the safest way is to perform a `claim()` on the task when a user starts working.
Then you can assume that every task that has an assignee is currently being worked on.

Comment: No, these are service tasks for example some software upgrade script. Also, I am hoping that there wont be any human intervention in entire flow.

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to achieve ... a synchronous service task execution is not persisted, so there is no way to get the info before its finished.

Comment: I have a requirement where a flow will have many long running tasks (service). Now I need some mechanism to show progress of flow (percentage completion and what task is currently executing) on UI. May be, I have to depend on polling historical service. Let me know if you think there could be a better alternative.

Comment: As I said, during the processing the state is not persisted, so you are blind.  You might want to check out the external task pattern ... good choice for long running executions anyway and at least it gives you some state control (claimed, running, ...)  if you really want to track progress, you will have to come up with a dedicated solution, nothing supported in camunda tat I can think of.